# Is it possible to get the group key of the Selected Item in a CollectionView group via the SelectionChanged routine?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using a collectionview in a xamarin.Forms app. I want to identify the Group Key of a SelectedItem.
The items in each group are not unique. Item can appear in multiple groups.
Perhaps I could use SelectionChangedCommand and specify the CommandParameter as the label.text in the GroupHeaderTemplate?
Or  possibly I redesign the item models to include the groupId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

Based on **[Xamarin.Forms - CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/)**, we could use `SelectionChanged` method to get the curren selected item. Then we can loop which group contain this item, therefore the property of Group also will get.

We will modifl **VerticalListEmptyGroupsPage.Xaml** code as follows:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
                    SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    IsGrouped="true">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                           Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="1" 
                           Text="{Binding Location}"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                       BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <CollectionView.GroupFooterTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Count, StringFormat='Total animals: {0:D}'}"
                       Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupFooterTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

And **VerticalListEmptyGroupsPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class VerticalListEmptyGroupsPage : ContentPage
{
    static GroupedAnimalsViewModel groupedAnimals;
    public VerticalListEmptyGroupsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        groupedAnimals= new GroupedAnimalsViewModel(true);
        BindingContext = groupedAnimals;
    }

    private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Animal selectedAnimal = e.CurrentSelection[0] as Animal;
        foreach (var animals in groupedAnimals.Animals)
        {
            foreach(var animal in animals)
            {
                if(animal == selectedAnimal)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(animals.Name);
                    DisplayAlert("Group Name", animals.Name, "OK");
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

===============================Update====================================

If there are multi groups contain the same Item, I think the best way is to design the model of item with containing the Group key.

For example, the `Animal` model could be designed as follows:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string GroupKey { set; get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

This way is similar with the foreign key of database.

Comment: Thank you but that will only work if all the animals are unique. If an animal appears in more than one group, it will not work.

Comment: @D.Foley Okey, if contains the same item in other Groups. It seems to need to design the model of item specially that contain the Group key inside it. Otherwise, we should can not know which group contain it. I will update the answer.

Comment: I took your advice about modifying my data models. I removed the Grouped CollectionView and instead use a CollectionView of the groups identifiers to start with. So the user selects from a list of the named groups. Which I then use to identify the group to use. I can keep my ObserveableCollection<Group> and use the user's group Id selection to index into this ObserveableCollection<Group>.