# Xamarin CollectionView Current Group

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, collectionview

How to get current visible group name in CollectionView when scrolling?
I want to show this info in page title.

```
myCollectionView.Scrolled += (object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e) =>
{
    int first_index = e.FirstVisibleItemIndex;
};
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to have each item contain a property with the group name. Otherwise, you'll have to do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64418828/199364).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the index and then get the matched item to get the group name.

```
   int first_index = e.FirstVisibleItemIndex;
        if (first_index!=0)
        {
            Name = ObservCollectionCategory[first_index-1].Category_Name;
            //The ObservCollectionCategory is the item source of Collectionview.
        }
```

And then binding the name of the title.

```
Title="{Binding Name}"
```